# C# with SQL server syntax error

Tags: c#, sql, database, syntax

So I have been looking at this for too long now and I am probably missing something But I cannot fathom what. I am receiving an error when trying to add a database entry in the third column titled "Unit Number" the error states that it is invalid syntax in this area when trying to add.

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::ProjectAssessment.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO Students (Student_Id,Student_name,Unit_number,Unit_grade) values(" +textBox1.Text+ ",'" +textBox2.Text+ ",'" +textBox3.Text+ ",'" +textBox4.Text+"')";
            SqlCommand exesql = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
            cn.Open();
            exesql.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Student record added", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            this.studentsTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Students);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Students (Student_Id,Student_name,Unit_number,Unit_grade) 
     values(" +textBox1.Text+ ",'" +textBox2.Text+ ",'" +textBox3.Text+ ",'" +textBox4.Text+"')";

                                                //^^^^ and others
```

On a single look, one can see that you are missing single quotes in your values. You can fix them, **but don't**. Use [`SqlParameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), they will not only save you from errors like these but also save you from SQL Injection.

So your code should look like:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::ProjectAssessment.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand exesql = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Students (Student_Id,Student_name,Unit_number,Unit_grade) values(@studentID, @studentName, @unitNumber, @unitGrade)", cn))
    {
        exesql.Parameters.Add("@studentID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox1.Text;
        exesql.Parameters.Add("@studentName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
        //... and others

        cn.Open();
        exesql.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }

    MessageBox.Show("Student record added", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    this.studentsTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Students);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Enclosing your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` object in `using` statement will ensure the disposal of resources. `using` will translate into `try-finally` block and in case of `SqlConnection` it will close/dispose the connection.

With the above code you don't need the `finally` block as connection will be diposed/closed after `using` statement's scope ends.

Comment: Copy/paste error: the cn object in the finally is now out of scope...so no finally required.

Comment: @ShellShock, thanks for pointing it out. Modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Students (Student_Id,Student_name,Unit_number,Unit_grade) values(" +textBox1.Text+ ",'" +textBox2.Text+ ",'" +textBox3.Text+ ",'" +textBox4.Text+"')";
```

should be

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Students (Student_Id,Student_name,Unit_number,Unit_grade) values(" +textBox1.Text+ ",'" +textBox2.Text+ "','" +textBox3.Text+ "','" +textBox4.Text+"')";
```

Please note that this is **VERY** unsafe, and prone to SQL injection!  For instance, if somebody decided that the student id should be `;DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --`, then your SQL statement would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO STUDENTS (Student_Id, Student_name, Unit_number, Unit_grade) values(;DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --, 'tb2val', 'tb3val', 'tb4val')
```

Depending on how things get executed, the first statement would throw a syntax error, the second statement (DROP TABLE STUDENTS;) would drop your table, and the rest would be treated as comments.

Whoops, there goes your students table!

You should use Habib's C# code to avoid this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I actually didn't know that I would have left it open to injection there so I appreciate the tip :)